# left indent in children div

Tags: html, css

how do I remove the indent in 1 px left of the blue div? I tried to reset border, no effect

```css
body 
{margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #222222;}

.container
{background: red; width: 1600px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto;}

.header
{background: blue; width: 100%; height: 64px; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="header"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: remove whitespace

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: Based on the code you gave us here, there is no reason for that 1px indent to be there. Could you post more of your code, like, div that is container of these two divs. Also, I put your code in codepen and it looks fine, so this problem is not reproducible

Comment: which is the browser that shows that 1px offset ? I do not see any as it is now.

Comment: I edited the post. Please look, I can see the offset of my blue div inside the red one by a pixel to the right. Why?

Comment: I see it on the screen shot, not in the snippet . which browser ?

Comment: Chrome 83.0.4103.61

Comment: okay, there is no need to set : width:100% to block elements it can produce effects like this. remove every width:100% of your code and test it again ;)

Comment: this is a kind of optical illusion, I guess the combination of the colors create this effect. If you try different colors you may not see it

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes! )) You are right! Thank you!

Comment: @G-Cyrillus this is only optical illusion, i've changed the colors and the indent disappeared. Thank you for advice anyway

Answer (score -1):

Judging your example, there seems to be some margin on the body element. You can remove it like this:

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```